# Setting up your own localhost server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to understand something that's been bugging me. I recently completed a frontend assignment that came with backend server/api node.js code. The server ran on localhost:4000 and the frontend ran on localhost:3000.

My question is, if it's a localhost server, does this generally mean it's not connected to any external database? I have the server/api code, I ran npm start on it and the response was "working!" Then I made api calls.

For context, the frontend made calls to a bakery api that pulled data for cupcakes: bases, frostings, etc. Below is an example of the db.json file.

```
{
  "bases": [
    {
      "key": "peanutButterBase",
      "name": "Peanut Butter Base",
      "price": 85,
      "ingredients": [
        "peanut butter cup cake"
      ]
    },
    ...
  ],
  "frostings": [
    {
      "key": "vanillaFrosting",
      "name": "Vanilla Frosting",
      "price": 15,
      "ingredients": [
        "vanilla frosting"
      ]
    },
    ...
 ],
```

This may be a ridiculous question, but is it possible to make a small app building your own mock server and api that merely runs locally? I want to use this for my portfolio but I want to build my own server/api that a hypothetical user could run and I want to make sure this is something that's actually possible and I'm looking at this correctly (i.e. this is not connected to say AWS or some other external server somewhere).

Btw, I understand this would mean it couldn't be an actual live site.

Comment: Yes you can create or fake the response from your server locally, there are several services out there for this, the simplest approach is to create json files that represents your API response there are some extensions for the browser such as: Web Server for Chrome, and also you can create your own using NodeJS and Express or HapiJS

Comment: `localhost` gets routed to your machine, but there's nothing otherwise special about it. An app running on your machine can make calls to databases or other services, whether those services are also local or running elsewhere. It is absolutely possible to build a fully local app, server, api, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to quickly implement a mock API server, that simply returns the JSON you've specified. It's a quick way to get a server running with some mock responses, and from your question sounds like it would be a good solution.